# google-autocomplete not working with shadcn-ui component `command`

Tags: google-maps, next.js, react-18, react-google-autocomplete

I want to implement Google Place Autocomplete using the `shadcn-ui` command component in Next.js 13. I was following a tutorial on youtube https://youtu.be/BL2XVTqz9Ek?si=XfnVHs1BRhhL8_Nn. However, in this tutorial, the author uses `@reach/combobox`, which does not work in Next.js 13

My code using shadcn-ui command component:

```
return (
    <Command>
      <CommandInput
        value={value}
        onValueChange={(value) => {
          setValue(value);
        }}
        disabled={!ready}
        placeholder="Search an address"
        className="combobox-input"
      />
      <CommandList>
        <CommandGroup>
          {status === "OK" &&
            data.map(({ place_id, description }) => (
              <CommandItem
                key={place_id}
                value={description}
                onSelect={handleSelect}
              />
            ))}
        </CommandGroup>
      </CommandList>
    </Command>
  );
};
```

result(no autocompletion ):
[image]

git repo given in tutorial:https://github.com/leighhalliday/google-maps-intro

his reach/combobox code :

```
return (
    <Combobox onSelect={handleSelect}>
      <ComboboxInput
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        disabled={!ready}
        className="combobox-input"
        placeholder="Search an address"
      />
      <ComboboxPopover>
        <ComboboxList>
          {status === "OK" &&
            data.map(({ place_id, description }) => (
              <ComboboxOption key={place_id} value={description} />
            ))}
        </ComboboxList>
      </ComboboxPopover>
    </Combobox>
  );
```

Comment: Well, if it does not work with the latest Next version, there's not much we can do but for you to either downgrade your Next, or file a github issue to the reach/combobox for it to be updated to work in Next.js 13. :'<

Comment: @Yrll "Yes, I agree, but I used the `Shadcn UI component` called 'Command' (which is an alternative for the 'Reach ComboBox' in Next.js 13). The mistake I made in the above code is that the 'onValueChange' event (since there is no 'onChange' event handler in the Shadcn UI component) is syntactically incorrect. It should be written as `value={value} onValueChange={setValue}`.

Comment: Oh yeah, it makes sense. Did this solve your issue? It would be great if you can put it here as an answer!

Comment: @Yrll Yes, this has resolved the autocomplete functionality, but the marker is not showing on the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Mistake

In the given code:

```
<Command>
  <CommandInput
    value={value}
    onValueChange={(value) => {
      setValue(value);
    }} //<---Error
  .....
</Command>
```

The mistake lies in the syntax of the onValueChange event handler. Since the Shadcn UI component doesn't use the onChange event handler, you need to set the value prop directly and pass a callback function to onValueChange.

### The Correction

Corrected code:

```
<Command>
  <CommandInput
    value={value}
    onValueChange={setValue}
    // ...
 
</Command>
```

### output:

[image]
Git Repo:https://github.com/Amith-AG/googelapis.git

Comment: Hey @Amith A G. Your repo link is dead, and I am also struggling to get this working.  Do you still have the code for this available? 

Comment: @ETFairfax, It was in private mode, Now you check it out:https://github.com/Amith-AG/googelapis.git

Comment: @ETFairfax, you can also try MUI Autocomplete as a alternative